# python manage.py runserver giving nameError: Python not defined

Tags: python, django

I am using the following command:

```
(env) C:\Users\Raktim_PC\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\mysite>python manage.py runserver
```

This results in the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 1, in <module>
    python#!/usr/bin/env python
NameError: name 'python' is not defined
```

I am getting started with Django framework and was following an online tutorial. I am in the outer mysite folder under which another mysite and mnagae.py resides when I am running the command leading to this error. Any ideas on what might be causing this and a possible solution?

Comment: Have you downloaded a python interpreter? By that saying, I mean have you downloaded python at all, or just the Django framework?

Comment: which os are you on

Comment: It appears that at the start of your `manage.py` python is written. (`python#!/usr/bin/env python`) it should only be `#!/usr/bin/env python`).

Comment: can you show manage.py code

Answer (score 0):

First possibility is that you have not installed python, but as you are following a course, that must have shown in the beginning how to do that. Second possibility is that
(i think you are using pycharm), you are not activating the virtual environment. Check inside your project, if there is a directory named `venv` then in your terminal run this command;

```
venv\scripts\activate
```

This will activate your environment. After that try again;

```
python manage.py runserver
```

There is also another possibility that you have installed python but didn't added it to your path.

To do so, go to your python installer, double click that (simply do all the steps which you did while installing python at first). During those steps, i think in the very first step, in the bottom-left corner, there will be an option to add python to path. Check that and install that again.

Note that adding path means now you can use python from anywhere.

Comment: The ops error shows that python is already running....

Comment: But it also shows python is not defined. These are the only possibilities i can think about.

Comment: Hi yes the virtual Environment was not activated, I did activate it but still getting the exact same error

Comment: Please check the last check. Maybe you have not added python to your path. Also remember to activate the virtual env, as they are automatically created in an IDE